# PHP MYSQL compare database value to POST value

Tags: php, mysql

This is a really simple one, I just can't get my head around it sorry. I have this PHP code which picks up my form value, then compares it with the value stored in the database. That works fine.

However I am not sure how to write this logic in terms of this query:

If posted value = database value {
// do something } else { // do something else }

```
if (empty($_POST['order_id']) === false) {
    // prepare data for inserting 
    $order_id = htmlentities(trim($_POST['order_id']));
    $order_id = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/","", $order_id);

    $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM listings WHERE order_id = $order_id");
    $row    = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

    echo $row['order_id'];

}
```

**SOLVED:**

Solved the question, was a silly one I know! Just needed this at the end of the code:

```
if($order_id === $row['order_id']) {
    echo 'found';
} else {
    echo 'not found';
}
```

Comment: Consider getting the number of results affected by your query and evaluate off of that value.  If that number is `0`, then we didn't find any matching results.  You can then take the user down the `else` path.  Otherwise, you can take them down the happy path.

Comment: does `$_POST['order_id']` contain an id that contains only one non-digit character. The `preg_replace` function in your code does remove only one non-digit character.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
If ($result->num_rows === 1) { do something } else { do something else }
```

Comment: `num_rows > 0` can also be considered, depending on the behaviour OP wants.

Comment: True, though he's launching mysqli_fetch_assoc only once, I assumed the result was expected to be only one.

Answer (score 0):

Since you did the business logic in your query you can just use

```
if( ! is_null($row)) {
   // do
} else {
   // nothing
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did I read too much into "If posted value = database value "?  Are you just referring to the order_id?

```
if ($row['listingName'] == $_POST['frm_listingName']) {
    // something
}
else {
    //something else
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this code:

```
if (empty($_POST['order_id']) === false) {
    // prepare data for inserting 
    $order_id = htmlentities(trim($_POST['order_id']));
    $order_id = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/","", $order_id);

    $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM listings WHERE order_id = $order_id");

    if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0)
    {
        //Match found. do something.
    }
    else
    {
        //No match found. do something.
    }
}
```

***N.B. In place of `mysqli_num_rows($result)` you can also use `$result->num_rows`***